# Convert data frame to linear format in R

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have a data frame in R as shown below

[image]

I want to convert it to a linear format with the column names repeating - like -

```
Value  Group
NA      A
2.5     A
4.0     A
...
4.0     B
NA      B
4.0     B
...
3.81    C
3.63    C
4.15    C
...
2.0     D
....
3.72    E
....
```

I know the long way to do it by extracting each column and appending another column with the group name (i.e "A", "B" etc) and then binding them all together.

Is there an efficient way to do this?

**EDIT**

Thanks for the inputs. Here is the `dput` output

```
structure(list(A = c(NA, 2.5, 4, 4, 5, NA, 4, 4, 4.52, 3.5), 
    B = c(4, NA, 4, NA, NA, 3, 3, 4, 4.44, 3.7), C = c(3.81, 
    3.63, 4.15, 3.47, 3.26, 3.08, 3.22, 3.94, 3.82, 3.27), D = c(2, 
    3.77, 4.5, NA, 5, NA, 3, 4.29, 4, 4), E = c(3.72, 3.78, 4.16, 
    3.97, 3.58, 3.13, 3.74, 4.04, 4.19, 3.57)), .Names = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Try reshape2::melt(df)

Comment: This must have been answered here hundreds of times before. Search for `[r] reshape wide long` - also see `reshape2::melt` and `stack` in base R.

Comment: `stack(DF)` will convert data.frame `DF` from its current wide form to long form.  Please do not use images -- instead show the output of `dput(DF)`  in your question and read [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. It might have been answered before but I could not find it - though I searched a lot for it - maybe I did not get the correct keywords. I just heard of  `dput` also now :)